# how to extract line features from a raster

Tags: raster, r, line

I have a raster of land cover types where roads are represented by pixels (1 pixel = 25m x 25m = 625 m²). Is there a way to extract line features (here roads) from a raster ?

```
## Create raster as an example:
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
r <- raster(ncols=90, nrows=50)
values(r) <- sample(1:10, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)

## Road raster
r[r[] < 10] <- 0
r[r[] >= 10] <- 1
plot(r)
```